# What objc function used to get app icon data for miniautrized windows?

Tags: objective-c, macos, icons

I had a question recently where I wanted to change the icon that is seen on the miniaturized windows. As seen pointed to the mini firefox icon on the minimized Firefox window in image here:

[image]

I learned about swizzling recently. I swizzled `[NSImage imageNamed:]` which fixed up a lot of the icons that `setApplicationIconImage` was not changing. But it doesn't get the miniaturized windows.

So my question is: Does anyone know which function its using to get the mini icon for drawing onto the mini window, is it like `[NSImage initWithData:]` or etc? I plan to swizzle that and feed the custom icon data.

Thanks

Comment: It's presumably part of the finder and it gets a specific image from the app icon collection in the bundle. Not sure exactly what you're trying to swizzle.

Answer (score 3):

You want to call `-setMiniwindowImage:` on your window. No swizzling or trickery required.

Comment: Aw dang ok thanks for this, so nothing to swizzle :( But i see this your thoughts which follow logic. But is it ok if I leave this unaccepted in case someone can say with fact for sure?

Comment: Hey @ipmcc forgive that but I missed your edit. `setMiniwindowImage` changes the whole window image and makes the mini icon not show. So it doesn't change the mini icon that overlays the window image :( So im like looking for something like "set mini icon overlaying mini window"